# Duplicates in consumer-group running on different servers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am facing the duplicates issue, when same consumer-group is running on two different servers and if a consumer-group from one server goes down, another server creates duplicates.
Can you please provide me a solution, how to prevent duplicates using scala?

This all configurations, I had tried, but duplicates still persists

```
  properties.put(StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE,true)
  properties.put("group.id", "groupid")
  properties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  properties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")

  properties.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION,5)
  properties.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG,"true")
  properties.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG,"all")
  properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates can't be removed with just a simple property. At least once delivery means you should expect duplicates.

I assume you have one partition that is being shared between both instances?

You need to configure a Consumer Rebalance Listener to commit the processed offsets during `onPartitionsRevoked`. This way, when the next instance hits `onPartitionsAssigned` of its listener, it can seek to the offsets of the committed, revoked instance (this would happen automatically, anyway)

You should also disable auto commits and try to enable transactions on your producer if you haven't already.

Note: Kafka Streams requires you to use consumerPrefix and producerPrefix static functions for internal client settings

Comment: I am new to Scala.
Can you share a code snippet for processing offsets during onPartitionsRevoekd and also of onPartitionsAssigned in scala.

Comment: I don't use Scala. This is a Java interface, which you'd need to port (or keep as Java), then add to your consumer client. There's example code in the docs https://kafka.apache.org/35/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html and you pass an instance of this to the subscribe function